# How deal with related fixtures

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I am using phpunit to test my CakePHP application, however, I have created two fixtures:- `A` and `B`. `A` gets inserted first and `B` second, but `B` also has a `a_id` field that I need to fill from the first fixture.

A good example of what I mean exists in the documentation: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#loading-fixtures-in-your-test-cases whereby `articles` and `comments` fixtures are shown, but it is never shown how `comments` is built.

How do I do this with CakePHP fixtures?

Comment: Fixture is just sample data what you can manually add. Here is a book about unti testing in cakephp: http://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484212134

Comment: @rrd thanks but since that book costs £17 it doesn't actually help, can you not explain what you mean more in a way that answers my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures are not related to each other. You need to build your associations manually in the data they contain. Fixtures are just data used in the tests [as the book explains it as well](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#fixtures). The data will get inserted into the test DB no matter if they're related or not. They'll only fail if you put constrains on the DB tables it generates and the FKs aren't present.

> When testing code that depends on models and the database, one can use fixtures as a way to generate temporary data tables loaded with sample data that can be used by the test. The benefit of using fixtures is that your test has no chance of disrupting live application data. In addition, you can begin testing your code prior to actually developing live content for an application.

So if you have comments create the records there with the FKs of your articles.